# Proof of addition rule of probabilities with 4 events

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

I need to show that, given a event space and four events. If the only non-empty intersections between them are $A\cap B$, $B\cap C$, $C\cap D$, $D\cap A$, then:

> $P(A\cup B\cup C\cup D)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)-P(A\cap B)-P(B\cap C)-P(C\cap D)-P(A\cap D)$

I think that i need to start with an equivalent form of $A\cup B\cup C\cup D$.

For example, i know that: $A\cup B=(A-B)\cup B$. But i dont know how to do this with the four sets.

Comment: Start with the _principle of inclusion/exclusion_. This will give you a sum with $4+6+4+1$ terms in it of which the $8$ above are a part, and all other terms (such as $P(A\cap B \cap C \cap D)$) turn out to be $0$. You may need to think a bit about this last point.

Comment: @DilipSarwate There is another way to do it?. If i use the principle of inclusion/exclusion i need to prove it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(A)-\mathbb P(A\cap B)=&\,\mathbb P(A\cap B^c)\\
\mathbb P(B)-\mathbb P(B\cap C)=&\,\mathbb P(B\cap C^c),\\
\mathbb P(C)-\mathbb P(C\cap D)=&\,\mathbb P(C\cap D^c),\\
\mathbb P(D)-\mathbb P(D\cap A)=&\,\mathbb P(D\cap A^c).
\end{align*}

Then, the right-hand side of the formula to be shown can be rewritten as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(A\cap B^c)+\mathbb P(B\cap C^c)+\mathbb P(C\cap D^c)+\mathbb P(D\cap A^c). \tag{$\spadesuit$}
\end{align*}
Given that $A\cap C=B\cap D=\varnothing$, these four events are pairwise disjoint, so $(\spadesuit)$ further equals:
$$\mathbb P\left[(A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap D^c)\cup(D\cap A^c)\right].$$
If we can show that the event between the brackets is the same as $A\cup B\cup C\cup D$, the proof will be complete.

$\textbf{Claim:}\phantom{---}(A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap D^c)\cup(D\cap A^c)=A\cup B\cup C\cup D$.

$\textit{Proof:}\phantom{---}$Since $A\cap B^c\subseteq A$, $B\cap C^c\subseteq B$, $C\cap D^c\subseteq C$, and $D\cap A^c\subseteq D$, it is clear that
$$(A\cap B^c)\cup(B\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap D^c)\cup(D\cap A^c)\subseteq A\cup B\cup C\cup D.$$ To see the other direction, suppose that $x\in A\cup B\cup C\cup D$. We need to show that $x$ is contained in at least one of $(A\cap B^c)$, $(B\cap C^c)$, $(C\cap D^c)$, or $(D\cap A^c)$.

$\textit{Case 1:}\phantom{---}$$x\in A$. If $x\in B^c$, then $x\in (A\cap B^c)$. If $x\in B$, then, since $x\in A\subseteq C^c$ (given that $A\cap C=\varnothing$), it follows that $x\in (B\cap C^c)$.

The other three cases ($x\in B$, $x\in C$, or $x\in D$) are completely analogous. $\blacksquare$

Comment: In the last step, if $x$ must be in at least one of the 4 sets, is not enough to show just one case?, so we dont need the other 3 analogous cases.

Comment: @Wyvern666 Not really, because we want to show here that $A\cup B\cup C\cup D\subseteq (A\cap B^C)\cup(B\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap D^c)\cup(D\cap A^c)$; that is, that $x\in A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ implies that $x\in(A\cap B^C)\cup(B\cap C^c)\cup(C\cap D^c)\cup(D\cap A^c)$. Now, the premise $x\in A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ can be true in four ways and all of them ought to be considered.